How to remove "always on top" status of a running application?
I use Goto Assist which can run on full screen. But in this mode, the Window is always on top.
I want to remove the "always on top" status of this Window.
I've found the DeskPins software, which is very useful and lightweight but it can only set the status, not unset.
Is there any other utility?

You may use the free AutoHotkey V1
to create yourself the application.
The following example script will set the active window to topmost for
F9 and undo that for F19:
F9::WinSet, AlwaysOnTop , On, A
F10::WinSet, AlwaysOnTop , Off, A

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a .ahk file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup.
Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

List of Keys
Hotkeys
WinSet command

